# Polymer 1.0 element property object binding, maintain structure

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I want to create a custom element that takes a JSON object as input.

```
<activity-tracker activity='{"title": "Lord Meowser", "description": "lala"}'></activity-tracker>
```

The element itself looks like this

```
<dom-module id="activity-tracker">
   <style>
     :host {
       display: block;
       box-sizing: border-box;
     }
   </style>

   <template>
     <p>{{activity}}</p>
     <p>{{activity.title}}</p>
   </template>

 </dom-module>
```

And the property binding

```
properties: {
  activity: {
     title: {
        type:String,
        value: '...'
     },
     description:{
        type:String,
        value: '...'
     }
   }
},
```

`<p>{{activity}}</p>` results in {"title": "Lord Meowser", "description": "lala"}

`<p>{{activity.title}}</p>` is empty

How can I map it? And how should I handle if user inserts something else, lets say activity="notanobject". Currently, defined internal object is just overwritten and the string is shown.

Comment: You will need to first convert your String into a JavaScript Object using `JSON.parse(myJsonString)`. You will most likely need a computed function that creates this object from the String whenever the String changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <dom-module id="activity-tracker">
    <style>
     :host {
       display: block;
       box-sizing: border-box;
     }
    </style>

   <template>
     <p>{{variable}}</p><!-- this shows [object Object]-->
     <p>{{variable.title}}</p> <!-- this shows Lord Meowser-->
     <p>{{variable.description}}</p> <!-- this shows lalala-->
   </template>

    <script>
      Polymer({
        is:"activity-tracker",
        properties:{
          variable:{
            type:Object,
            value: function(){return {};}
          }
        }

      });
    </script>  

</dom-module> 

<activity-tracker variable='{"title": "Lord Meowser", "description": "lala"}'></activity-tracker>
```

This should work.

Comment: Do you know if this works when rendering from a react component like so `React.createElement("activity-tracker", {variable: {title:"the title", description: "the description"}})`