# How to pass Polymer object properties when rendering from React components (no JSX)

Tags: reactjs, polymer-1.0

I've found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32012950/1436359) showing how to bind object properties to attributes specified in the HTML tag for a Polymer component.

What I want to do is to pass those same properties when rendering from a React component like so:

```
var myComponent = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function(){
    },
    render: function() {
        var activities = this.props.activities.map(function(activity) {
            return React.createElement("activity-tracker", {variable: {"title": activity.title, "description": activity.description}});
        });
        return React.createElement("div", null, activities);
    }
};
```

I'm trying to avoid using JSX altogether.

`activity-tracker` is the Polymer component

```
<dom-module id="activity-tracker">
    <template>
        <p>{{variable.title}}</p>
        <p>{{variable.description}}</p>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is:"activity-tracker",
            properties:{
                variable:{
                    type:Object,
                    value: function(){return {};}
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

**Update**

I’ve found a [this post](https://github.com/jscissr/react-polymer/issues/5) where they pass the values using a `ref` function but [I’m not sure](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3234) if that is the best way to do it.

```
...
return React.createElement("activity-tracker", {
    ref: function (ref) {
            if (!ref) return;
            ref.variable = {title: activity.title, description: activity.description};
        }
    });
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible because of React's virtual DOM.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question with a solution I found for doing the same thing in [react-polymer](https://github.com/jscissr/react-polymer), altough I'm not sure if that is a supporterd use case.